# Closing the read end of socket while keeping the send end alive

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a server which receives and sends data.

When i make server down, I wish to stop receiving the data abruptly but wish to keep the send active so that the data in buffer is sent.

IS there any params to be set during setsockopt and any other option as closing the socket will close both send and receive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `shutdown()` function to do this. From `man 2 shutdown`:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  #include <sys/socket.h>
>
>  int shutdown(int s, int how);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The shutdown() call causes all or part of a full-duplex connection on the
>      socket associated with s to be shut down.  If how is SHUT_RD, further
>      receives will be disallowed.  If how is SHUT_WR, further sends will be
>      disallowed.  If how is SHUT_RDWR, further sends and receives will be dis-
>      allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shutdown() in socket functionality, to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

> 'wish to keep the send active so that
>   the data in buffer is sent.'.

Data in what buffer? Your output stream or writer? Just close it. It will be sent.

If you're referring to the socket send buffer you have even less to worry about.

The shutdown() solution has platform-dependent effects at the other (sending) end. On some platforms (Windows) the sender will get a 'connection reset'. On other platforms (Linux) the sender will fill up the receiver's receive buffer and his own send buffer and eventualy stall. On other platforms (BSD) the sender will keep merrily writing forever, which is probably the best implementation but it wastes bandwidth.